# Read response from MongoDB operation

Tags: mongodb

in my application I insert/update some documents.
I would need to act somehow depending on the result of the operation, but I do not understand how to use the WriteResult object.

This is the toString() of an update succesfully terminated:

Update write result: { "serverUsed" : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 1 , "updatedExisting" : true}

Now, from the documentation I read that getLastError methods are deprecated.
I've getN that just tell me how many record has been updated (meaningless with inserts).
I've no methods to retrieve the OK value.

Do you have any suggestion on how manage the WriteResult object to understand the result of an operation?
Thanks in advance,
Samuel

Comment: Can you give a specific example of how you want to use the WriteResult object? What driver are you using?

Comment: you're right sorry: mongo-java-driver.2.12.3

Comment: the goal is to understand somehow if the operation (update/insert/remove) fails or success

Comment: If you're using a later version of the Java driver, you should use WriteConcern instead of WriteResult and rely on the database call to throw an exception on failure. Most of the methods of WriteResult are now deprecated in favor of this approach, as you mentioned. OK is just true/1 or false/0 as the operation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I was using another framework that was hiding this deprecation, but since having removed that framework, I also came upon this problem.

I was also puzzled as you were on what the documentation was trying to say. Having gone through the MongoDB source code it looks like what was previously this:

```
WriteResult result = collection.update(query, update, true, false);
if (!result.getLastError().ok()) {
    // handle error here
}
```

now looks like this:

```
try {
    collection.update(query, update, true, false);
}
catch (CommandFailureException e) {
    CommandResult result = e.getCommandResult();
    // you can use result.ok() here, but it should almost always return false.
}
```

`MongoException` is a runtime exception that has several subclasses including `CommandFailureException`, so you may want to take a look at the javadocs [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/MongoException.html)